# When a process writes to a file

Tags: file, process, createfile

Generally, when a process writes to a file, e.g a python script running open('file', 'w').write('text'), what are the exact events that occur? By that I mean something among the lines of 'process A loads file from hard disk to RAM, process B changes content then ...'. I've read about IPC and now I'm trying to dig deeper and understand more on the subject of processes. I couldn't find a thorough explanation on the subject, so if you could find one or explain I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The example of "a python script running `open('file', 'w').write('text')`" is heavily OS-dependent.  The only processes involved here are the process running the Python interpreter, which, e.g. on Linux, can sometimes execute in userspace and sometimes execute in kernel space, and possibly some kernel-only processes, with any IPC, if required, happening inside the kernel.  There is no particular requirement that everything down to the disk read itself cannot be handled on the user's process when it is running in kernel mode, but in practice, there may be other processes involved.  This is OS- and even driver-specific behavior.

In this particular example (which isn't great, because it relies on the automatic cPython close when the variable goes out of scope), the Python process makes a system call to open a file, one to write the file, and one to close the file.  These are all *blocking* -- that is, they do not return until the results are ready.  When the process blocks, it is put on a queue waiting for some event to occur to make it ready to run again.

The opposite of this is asynchronous I/O, which can be performed by polling, by callbacks, or by the select statement, which can block until any one of a number of events has occurred.

But when most people talk about IPC, they are not usually talking about communication between or with kernel processes.  Rather, they are talking about communication between multiple user processes and/or threads, using semaphores, mutexes, named pipes, etc.  A good introduction to these sorts of things would be any tutorial information you can find on using pthreads, or even the Python threads and multiprocessing modules.  There are examples there for several simple cases.

The primary difference between processes and threads on Linux is that threads share an address space and processes each have their own address space.  Python itself adds the wrinkle of the GIL, which limits the utility of threads in Python somewhat.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, I really appreciate it. You have certainly helped me both with your written explanation and with the tutorial references. I'll look into these and hopefully get a better grasp on the subject. My thanks.